# Change the font colour of time display at certain time period of this clock

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this python script named clock.py.

Here is the source code.

```
# Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-a-digital-clock-using-tkinter/

# importing whole module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to
# retrieve system's time
from time import strftime

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')


# This function is used to
# display time on the label

def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl.config(text=string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)


# Styling the label widget so that clock
# will look more attractive
lbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
            background='purple',
            foreground='white')

# Placing clock at the centre
# of the tkinter window
lbl.pack(anchor='center')
time()

mainloop()
```

In the time period from 2345hrs to 0000hrs, I want to change the font colour to bright red so that the clock time display is more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question.

```
def time():
    current_time = strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    # Check if the time is between 23:45 and 00:00
    if '23:45' <= current_time <= '23:59':
        lbl.config(text=current_time, foreground='red')  # Set font color to red
    else:
        lbl.config(text=current_time, foreground='white')  # Set font color to white

    lbl.after(1000, time)
```